# MIPS Load Word [Address and Content Confusion]

Tags: mips

If I were to use the load word command

```
  lw $t0, 4($t0)
```

and this table

```
  Address   Content
    100       120
    112       108
    132       136
    136       112

    #s1 is initialised to 0
    #t0 is initialised to 112
```

The confusion I have is that if I were to assignment the value of 4($t0) to $t0, what would happen to the original address of $t0? and that if the question were to say it is initialized to 112, will it be referring to the address or value?

Answer (score 1):

Before the execution of `lw $t0, 4($t0)` the register `$t0` is expected to contain a base address.

The instruction then loads the word located at the address `$t0+4` into register `$t0`. After the execution, $t0 holds the value stored in that address ($t0+4), and the previous value is "lost" (that is, it is overwritten by the memory read).

Any value can be interpreted as an address and any address can be interpreted as a value (i.e. they are just 32bit values). It is up to your code to give meaning to those values. It seems like `$t0` is meant to be the base address of an array prior to the instruction and to contain some value (the contents of index 1 of the array if we suppose `$t0` was holding the base address of the array) after the instruction is executed.